# How do I make a setter function demonstrate exception handling in a List using c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, list, exception, playlist

I am trying to create a setter function where you can replace a song at a certain position within a list, while still demonstrating exception handling. To do this, I am focusing on setEntry().

Here's my List class:

```
class List
{
private:
    static const int CHUNK_SIZE=100;
    ItemType *list;
    int numItems;
    int maxItems;
public:
    // default constructor and destructor
    List()
    {
      numItems = 0;
      maxItems = CHUNK_SIZE;
      list = new ItemType[CHUNK_SIZE];
    }

    ~List()
    {
      delete[] list;
    }
    
    // list member functions
    bool isEmpty()  const 
    {
      return numItems==0;
    }


    int getLength() const 
    { 
      return numItems; 
    }
    bool insert(int pos, const ItemType& item);

    bool remove(int pos);
    
    // clear the list
    // clear can simply set numItems to zero.  The array list may still contain
    // items already inserted into the list, but since numItems is zero, there
    // isn't any way to get at them using getEntry() or setEntry()
    void clear()
    {
      numItems = 0;
    }
    
    // return entry at postion pos
    // throw invalid_argument if pos<1 or pos>getLength()
    ItemType getEntry(int pos) const;
    
    // set entry at postion pos to item
    // throw invalid_argument if pos<1 or pos>getLength()
    // changes whatever is inside the position to that item. swap. 
    void setEntry(int pos, const ItemType& item);
    
};
```

My teacher wants setEntry to set the position (pos) to the song (item), and throw invalid_argument if pos < 1 || pos > getLength(). When I try to setEntry() in my main method, it just throws the exception. In my head, (list[pos] = item) seems right, since you don't have to shift all the data to the right when you add, you just have to replace it. What's going on? How can I still test for the exception while having my code run?

Here's setEntry():

```
template<class ItemType>
void List<ItemType>::setEntry(int pos, const ItemType& item)
 {
    list[pos] = item;

      if (pos < 1 || pos > getLength())
      {
            throw invalid_argument("ERROR: setEntry() using invalid position");
      }
 }
```

Here's my main method:

```
int main()
{
    List<string> songs;
    char goAgain = 'y';
    int trackNumber;
    string trackName;
    
    // Insert some songs into our list

    songs.setEntry(2, "Bohemian Rhaspody");

    songs.insert(1, "Bohemian Rhaspody");

    songs.insert(2, "The Highway Song");

    songs.insert(3, "In the Loop");

    songs.insert(4, "Lovesong");

    songs.insert(5, "Blow The Whistle");

    songs.remove(1);
      
    cout << "Welcome!  There are " << songs.getLength() << " tracks.\n";
    while (goAgain!='n')
    {
        trackNumber = getTrack();
        try
        {
            trackName = songs.getEntry(trackNumber);
        }
        catch (invalid_argument arg)
        {
            cout << arg.what() << endl;
            trackName = "No Track";
        }
        cout << "Your track name is " << trackName << endl;
        cout << "Go again? (y/n) ";
        cin >> goAgain;
    }
    
    cout << "you're ready to rock!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

And the error it outputs:

```
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::invalid_argument: ERROR: setEntry() using invalid position
[1]    48422 abort
```

Comment: Your first call to `setEntry` uses position 2 although the list is empty. Also, you should do the error check _before_ assigning the item to an invalid position.

Comment: If you're going to test a given argument (`pos`, in your `setEntry`), then do that test **before** you use the thing. Your function uses `pos` before it makes the check.

Comment: There's a highly technical term for this kind of a bug, it's called "putting the cart before the horse". First you check for bad input and throw an exception, and ***then*** proceed forward, if the input is not bad.

Comment: `list[]` is indexed from `0` upwards, not `1`. Also should you not check for errors *before* trying to insert the item?

Comment: What others have said above. Plus, the valid ranges are from `0` up to and including  `length-1`.  That is, it should be `pos >= getLength()` not `pos > getLength()`.